# Object property undefined but has value in Firefox debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, arcgis-js-api

TL;DR
Property is seen as `undefined` in `console.log` but (every) browser displays its value in developer tools.

I've tested this weird behavior on 2 machines (Windows and Linux) and 2 browsers (Chrome and Firefox). Code first (invoked 2 times in a loop):

```
var layer = map.getLayer(map.graphicsLayerIds[i]);
console.log(layer);
console.log(layer.name);
```

Result in browsers developer tools:
[image: firefox console]
[image: firefox debug]

As you can see layer is an object (to be specific a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html) object). After clicking on it in firefox console I can see its properties as shown on the second image. However **some** of these properties are undefined although I can clearly see their values (and these values have expected content).

My teammates, also tested this one on their computers and have exactly the same output. What is going on?

EDIT:
Here is documentation [map.getLayer()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#getlayer)

Comment: Probably, the properties are added **after** your `console.log` call.

Comment: I'm assuming map.getLayer is async?

Comment: console.log of an object will keep the reference of the object and update the values, while console.log of a string will just try to print it's value